# Unsupported usampler

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have an Intel HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2) GPU. Installed MESA 13.1 drivers on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I wrote a shader that makes use of an `usampler2D`, and therefore was trying to use `#extension GL_EXT_gpu_shader4`. Apparently this is not supported by this GPU, but `#extension GL_EXT_texture_integer` is. Also, `#version 130` is supported.

However, I cannot use `usampler2D` nor `texture2D(usampler2D)` using none of the combinations of

```
#version 120
#extension GL_EXT_texture_integer
uniform usampler2D tex;
void main() { texture2D(tex, vec2(0., 0.)); }
```

nor

```
#version 130
uniform usampler2D tex;
void main() { texture2D(tex, vec2(0., 0.)); }
```

None of the shader version compile successfully. Both yield errors of undefined overload of `texture2D(usampler)`, only `texture2D(sampler)` overloads are apparently supported.

```
0:20(18): error: no matching function for call to `texture2D(usampler2D, vec2)'; candidates are:
0:20(18): error:    vec4 texture2D(sampler2D, vec2)
0:20(18): error:    vec4 texture2D(sampler2D, vec2, float)
```

Is there an alternative of using `usampler2D` uniforms on this architecture? Or maybe I'm using wrong driver configs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`texture2D` cannot be used with `usampler`s of any kind. `texture2D` was deprecated from GLSL 1.30 and removed in GLSL 1.50.

The [correct function to use is `texture`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Basic_texture_access). This requires GLSL 1.30 or higher, or [EXT_gpu_shader4](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/gpu_shader4.txt).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I need this to be compatible with #version 120 for OSX systems. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @manatttta: As I said: "this requires GLSL 1.30 or higher, **or EXT_gpu_shader4**." The point being that you're requiring *the wrong extension*

Comment: On OSX, using version 120 and  EXT_gpu_shader4 yields `Invalid call of undeclared identifier 'texture`, but  `texture2D` works with `usampler2D` argument